# Using database constraints in web development or just in application logics

Tags: webforms, constraints

I would like to ask about using database constraints in web development. When I designe a web form with some restrictions, they must be defined in the web form. Should I define them in database too? Or it is just a duplicity?
If I use database constraints I can guarantee data integrity for 100 %. But database constraints makes more difficult web development and debugging errors.

Just question that we discussed between web developer and database administrator.

Comment: some restrictions: what does it mean?

Comment: We have a web form, where we have fields like distance (constraint >= 0), check box, which affects another field (must be empty if check box is not check), field for inserting URL. 
The form writes data on database. 
We have defined constraints for fields in web form, ex. if user writes distance less then 0, immedialy see the error. For our web developer, these types of constrains is fully sufficient and the application itself will solve all limitations in the data. Using database constraints is redundant.
I´m asking for your an opinion on whether to use database constraints or not.

Comment: It depends by the software. UI could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit of a open ended question.

But, yes, you should define most of the basic constraints in the database.

However, those constraints in most cases don't amount to much. So, say allow nulls, or enforcing referential integrity is a VERY good idea.

However, for somthing like say a discount entered can't be more then say 20% or some such, or things like some value must be > 0? Then that kind of stuff is better left to your code + UI.

So, for basic things like default values (bit field say 0 for false as a default), things like allow a column to be null, and for SURE enforcing RI is a good thing.

but, for those basic values like must be > 0 or must be < 20 or whatever? that in most cases does not make sense to put in the database, and one big reason?

If the database triggers that error, it 99% of the time too late for the user to do anything about such cases, and then you wind up having to write that code to do the same thing in the UI and give the user a friendly message and workflow anyway.

So in general, yes, build such rules in the UI + code. While in some cases such as attempting to add a child record (say adding a invoice without first having added a customer record ?). In that case, you have both the database RI and also have to write the code in the UI. But for those smaller types of "rules" such as > 0, or whatever? That you don't need to put in the database, and as you note, in most cases it will just get in your way.